# Loading text file im modelsim-VHDL

Tags: vhdl

Loading text file(pixel of image) im modelsim: this code throws an Error about infile.

I want to read the file, sum each data value by adding 10 and put the result in outputlink file:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.STD_logic_arith.all;
USE STD.TEXTIO.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;

ENTITY filEx IS 
    port(clk : in std_logic);
END filEx;

ARCHITECTURE TEST OF filEx IS
    signal d1,d2,d3 :integer;

BEGIN

    PROCESS (clk)
        variable outLine : LINE; 
        variable inLine  : LINE;
        variable a       : integer;
        file input_file  : text open read_mode is "C:\Users\K56C\Desktop\test.txt";
        file outFile     : TEXT is out "outputlink";
    BEGIN
        if not endfile (inFile) then
            READLINE(inFile, inLine);
            READ(inLine, a );

            a := a + 10;
            WRITE(outLine, a);
            WRITELINE(outFile, outLine);
        end if;
    END PROCESS;
END TEST;
```

Comment: There isn't a "C:\Users\K56C\Desktop\test.txt", I looked. Matter of fact I can't even find a "C:\". So, first we have to guess what's in the file. Then we have to guess what the error is, and then we have to guess what your question about it is. Is that all, or do you want an answer too?

Comment: You declare `input_file` and readline `inFile`. The use clause for package std_logic_arith is not needed in your sample code. @BrianDrummond is indicating your code isn't a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) absent either a clear problem statement or an input file (preferably with a local file path avoiding OS agnostic issues).

Comment: @David : Thanks for putting the effort in. I should probably have spotted the mistake. But undoubtedly, the actual error message would have pointed right at it. Boy, was I grumpy this afternoon!

Comment: @Brian, morning here, is the question clear now?

Answer (score 1):

Fixing the identifier mismatch with the input file declaration:

```
library ieee;
-- use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use std.textio.all;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity filex is 
    port ( 
        clk: in std_logic
    );
end entity filex;

architecture test of filex is 
    signal d1,d2,d3: integer;
begin
    process (clk)
        variable  outline:      line; 
        variable  inline:       line;
        variable  a:            integer;
        -- file input_file: text open read_mode is "c:\users\k56c\desktop\test.txt";
        file infile: text open read_mode is "test.txt";
        file outfile: text is out "outputlink";
    begin
        if not endfile (infile) then
            readline(infile, inline);
            read(inline , a );
            a := a + 10;
            write(outline, a);
            writeline(outfile, outline);
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture test;
```

and changing the input file path to something OS agnostic (a local file in this case) and your code analyzed, elaborated and after providing the input file ran.

Without knowing the contents of your file providing an input file with a single line containing "42", the output file contained "52".

And that says you made one little mistake which happened to show up during analysis.

Comment: Tank you my frnd."ALLAH" hafiz